# How can I draw Axis three level ticks in OxyPlot

Tags: c#, graph, axis, oxyplot

I want to draw Axis three level ticks in OxyPlot but it provide only two ticks. Major and Minor.

[image: TwoTicks Major is long, Minor is short]

Major is long
Middle is middle   <-- I want to draw this
Minor is short

How can I draw Axis three level ticks in OxyPlot

Answer (score 1):

OxyPlot only supports [major and minor ticks](http://docs.oxyplot.org/en/latest/models/axes/#major-minor-intervals) so you'll have to fork the [project](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot) and modify it to suit your needs to support *middle ticks*. It won't be very easy though, since the code involves quite a lot of math.

Here are some classes that hande major and minor ticks. There are many more but you'll get a good idea from those.

1. [AxisUtilities.cs](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/blob/develop/Source/OxyPlot/Axes/AxisUtilities.cs)
2. [AngleAxisRenderer.cs](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/blob/4db3c45a2acc86b7b11816462cb4f2850c709a11/Source/OxyPlot/Axes/Rendering/AngleAxisRenderer.cs)
3. [AxisRendererBase](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/blob/9d9ec26dcaa8bb9698762ff40c826cffc877b4f2/Source/OxyPlot/Axes/Rendering/AxisRendererBase.cs)

To find the rest of the classes, you can do a [search for *major*](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Major&type=Code) and find the parts of the code that deal with ticks. Also, you could just get the code compiling on your machine and go from there.

Comment: Thx, I Try it. yes actually it was very difficult
So i want to Idea that I ask to stackoverflow
I cann't undetstand ticks mechanism
Do you have any ideas? I try axis 2 adds ,Oxyplot support only  X axis Y axis so I cann't draw ticks